# UI5 Tree Table expanded node list

Tags: sapui5

I Have a [tree table](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.TreeTable.html) Where i need to get the expanded nodes

right now i have code to take the rowIndex which are expanded

```
<table:TreeTable selectionMode="MultiToggle"
    enableSelectAll="false" rowHeight="40" 
    toggleOpenState="onOpenParent"
```

Controller i have the code as below

```
onOpenParent : function(oControlEvent)
      {
          var rowIndex = oControlEvent.getParameter('rowIndex');
          ....
```

Which will tell the rowIndex which are open.

Problem:

When the treemodel is changed the rowIndex are not valid for example i have 10 rows, after some thing the tree model is changed and became only 5 rows.

if i have rowIndex as 7 which is expanded the 7 is invalid now because we have only 5 rows.

So need to clear these index if it reaches invalid state. OR i need to take the expanded nodes after rendering.

Which is better way and HOW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is way which i found we can do it. but some one please suggest ifa nay other way to do it.

We can find which are expanded after updating data to the model or table onAfterRendering we can use below code

```
         var allRows = this.oTable.getRows();
         for( r=0;r<allRows.length;r++)
         {
             var isExpanded = this.oTable.isExpanded(r);
             console.log("Row : "+r+" isExpanded:"+isExpanded);
         }
```